# Tastypie + Password reset

Tags: python, django, angularjs, tastypie

I'm currently building an app with a python backend (django/tastypie) and a frontend built with Angular.js. I'd like to create a password reset form but I can't find a proper way to do it. It seems like the password reset view depends from Django's templates. ([Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset))

I can't find a clean way to integrate Django reset method without using any of the templates (I want to use my own templates with Angular.js).

Any advice on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this question has been unanswered for quite some time so I don't know if you are still looking for a solution but I came across a blog post [here](http://michalcodes4life.wordpress.com/2014/08/24/password-reset-for-mobile-application-with-django-and-tastypie/) that provides a pretty good solution to the problem.

Essentially you need to create two api endpoints: one to initiate the password reset (send an email with a link to a reset form) and another to accept the new password.

The link in the email could be a route to a dedicated page in your angular app along with a token (something like /reset_password/:reset_token). You would strip of the token and send it back with the form data to the second endpoint.